# CakePHP 2.2 / AclExtras / aco_sync takes ages to execute

Tags: acl, cakephp-2.2

I have a intraweb application which uses AclExtras.

When i execute in shell

```
./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

it takes about 4-5 minutes (!!!).

Is there maybe something not correctely set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it could take that much time because it just needs it to regenerate all permissions, or:

- If you're running it on an old or not powerful enough server it could still run slow.
- If you have problems on the DB server due to high loads.
- If you custom coded something it could run slower if not optimized.
- .... Whatever else

There is no way to say why it takes 4-5 minutes if you do not provide any code and more detailed set up information, but on the other hand it could just be so resource intensive that the Shell requires these minutes to complete it's task... So a question like "it takes about 4-5 minutes (!!!).Is there maybe something not correctly set up?" is no good in this case. Please [check this out on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you. I was really just wondering if it could be normal to take such an amount of time. And it seems that it can. The acos table has around 120k entries at the moment.